# Image crossorigin - why can it not contain a data url from canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-domain

After creating an image with the crossorigin attribute I am able to use getImageData and toDataURL on an image from another domain that i control however if i try to set the src attribute of the image to a data url that is retrieved from canvas it throws a security error. If I set the crossorigin attribute to null before setting it's src to a data url from the canvas it works.

Why is this?